# ISREF only works if external workbook is already open

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a sheet and name it based on the contents of a cell in another workbook if that sheet does not already exist. Code seems to work fine if the other workbook is already open, but if I have to open the workbook through my code, the ISREF doesn't work. If the workbook is opened with the code it will create a new sheet and then try to name it and result in an error because there's already a sheet with that name.

```
If AlreadyOpen = False Then Workbooks.Open ("Class Attendance.xlsm")
For i = 2 To Workbooks("Class Attendance.xlsm").Worksheets("Attendance").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sName = Workbooks("Class Attendance.xlsm").Worksheets("Attendance").Cells(i, 4) & ", " & Workbooks("Class Attendance.xlsm").Worksheets("Attendance").Cells(i, 5)

    'If member sheet already exists add dates
    If Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)") = True Then

    'If member sheet doesn't exist, create one
    ElseIf sName <> ", " Then
        Set WS = thisWB.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        WS.Name = sName
        Cover.Activate
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: In your code you have the workbook full path in this line `Workbooks.Open ("Class Attendance.xlsm")` ?

Comment: I think that will work in the active sheet.  Try CVERR https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839168.aspx

Comment: While a workbook is closed, Excel will not be able to find it unless you provide the full path

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly acceptable to use `On Error` statements carefully in these situations:

```
Public Sub AddSheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws as Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks("Book1") 'if workbook is open
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("../../Book1.xlsx") 'if workbook is closed
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("SomeName") 'if worksheet exists
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ws Is Nothing Then 'if worksheet doesn't exist
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets.Count)
        ws.Name = "SomeName"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice idea +1 , I was going with some complex `Match` will looping

Comment: in code: `Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets.Count)` code needs `Worksheets` reference: `Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answers which utilises helper functions:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook: Set wbSrc = GetWorkBook(".\Class Attendance.xlsm", True) 'Full Path Required
    Dim sName As String, ws As Worksheet

    With wbSrc.Worksheets("Attendance")
        For i = 2 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            sName = .Cells(i, 4) & ", " & .Cells(i, 5)
            If Not WorkSheetExists(ThisWorkbook, sName) Then
                Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                ws.Name = sName
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function GetWorkBook(ByVal sFullName As String, Optional ReadOnly As Boolean) As Workbook
    Dim sFile As String: sFile = Dir(sFullName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWorkBook = Workbooks(sFile)
    If GetWorkBook Is Nothing Then Set GetWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(sFullName, ReadOnly:=ReadOnly)
End Function

Function WorkSheetExists(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal strName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   WorkSheetExists = Not wb.Worksheets(strName) Is Nothing
End Function
```